# What type of word is "must"?

Tags: british-english, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

First of all, let me give you these example sentences:

- there is a storm
- there was a storm
- there has been a storm
- there had been a storm

Every one of the above examples expresses that there certainly is/was/... a storm.

Now I would like to express that I think that there maybe is/was/... a storm, for example because I saw all the fallen trees. In the present tense it is very clear: *there must be a storm*.

If I want to say the same in the past perfect the word *must* won't change: *there must have been a storm*.

What I do not understand is what type of word *must* is this example is. Why doesn't it change? If I say *I must go to school* it changes to *I had to go to school* in past perfect because *must* is a Modal Auxiliary then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that *there must had been a storm* is not grammatical in most varieties of English. *There must have been a storm* is what I think you meant.

Secondly, the answer is that *must* is a modal verb, but like *could* it hasn't got a past tense. (Historically, they are both past tenses, and in some senses *could* still functions as the past of *can*. *Must* is isolated, with no corresponding present-tense verb).

If you want to express obligation in the past, *must* is not available, so you need to substitute another expression, typically *have to* (which means almost the same as *must*, and has a past tense: *had to*).

Comment: Thank you so far! But is there a reason why *must had been* is not grammatical? And how would the sentence look like if we used present tense for the word *must*? *There had to ... a storm*?

Comment: @ElasticLamb. Because modals, without exception, are followed by the base form of the verb (sometimes called the infinitive), not  by a tensed from such as _had_. The verb in question can be another auxiliary, eg _must have been_, _must be seen_. I don't understand the second question in your comment. _There must be a storm. There has to be a storm. There must have been a storm. There had to be a storm._

Comment: Alright, that I have understood. But what exactly means *have been* then? I thought it would be present perfect. Sorry for my weird questions!

Comment: Ah, @ElasticLamb, this gets a bit complicated. With non finite forms, _have_ with the past participle is past, but not necessarily perfect, in meaning. So _there must have been a storm_ (which only makes sense with the epistemic meaning of _must_ ) means something like "I conclude that there was/has been a storm".